# jQuery, only fire if li is clicked on and NOT an a tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example2.com">Example2</a></li>
</ul>
```

The li's have a width set by css to 400px;

I'm trying to write some jquery that only fires if the li is clicked, but NOT the a tag.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the event in the click handler, look at the event.target / event.originalTarget

This should give you an indication which element caused the event and you can either process it or ignore it.

```
function clickHanlder (e)
{
   if (e.target.tagName != "A") { return; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**e.stopPropagation();**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the child element:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   alert('This will be alerted on the li, not the anchor inside');
});

$('li a').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cpX6/1/)

Comment: @Dom Could do, I think stopPropagation() works just fine in this use case though

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in "e" in your function and then check the target. Just read Dory's comment and I'd agree. In my opinion it is the best route and always works.

```
$('element').on('click', function (e) {
    if(e.target == 'check the tag here'){
       // do something.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/w2zBK/

```
$('li a').click(function(event){
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){
alert('li here');
});
$('ul li a').click(function(){
return false;
});
```